# java/php Bridge: Executing custom functions of tomcat app on wamp server (php)

Tags: tomcat, wampserver, php-java-bridge

As the title says I want to use classes and functions provided by a web app running on tomcat 7 in a php script running on a wamp server.
Although I did find something related, I did not find anything step by step on how to execute custom java classes and functions in php.
I did manage to make this work though:

```
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."JavaBridge/java/Java.inc";
    $System = java("java.lang.System");
    echo $System->getProperties();
```

In the end I want to be able to do something like that:

```
    $abc= java("myproject.abc");
```

where abc is a custom class in `myproject`.
Btw. I did look in the offical guide (http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/webapp.php) but it either isn't helpful or I just don't get it. I also found that stackoverflow post ([How to call custom java methods from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204116/how-to-call-custom-java-methods-from-php)), problem is, I don't really now what he means by

> Now just copy your java jar file in tomcat /webapps/JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib/ folder...

What `java.jar` files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `java.jar` was meant that you bundle the .java/packages of your application whose fuctions/classes you want to use into a .jar.

In Eclipse: Select the packages/files -> right click -> Export, Select JAR file -> Next -> Check "Export generated class files and resources" -> finish.

Now all you have to do is copy that `.jar` file into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the JavaBridge application (if you don't have one already, just let tomcat deploy your `JavaBridge.war`), and restart the tomcat server. You can call your functions then like that:

```
    <?php
        define("JAVA_HOSTS", "localhost:8080"); ////fill in on whatever port you're server is running on so Java.inc knows with whom it should connect
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."JavaBridge/java/Java.inc"; ////specify where on your apache server the Java.inc file is
        $object=new Java("test.classname");
        $object->Method();
    ?>
```