# trouble getting link to user-defined java class from php using php-javaBridge

Tags: java, php, eclipse, xampp, php-java-bridge

We need to call a user defined java function within php code,so javaBridge connection is needed.

we have done the php-javabridge-configuration and it is working fine.
http://phprambabu.blogspot.in/2016/04/php-javabridge-configuration.html

To connect php with java class, we are running the java class from eclipse on tomcat server, HTTP port:8086 and mentioning the same port number in java.inc file, and its path is added in php file as "required_once(Java.inc)".

-> this shows error in Java.inc file
but changes made in Java.inc seems correct according to other resources found on internet and stackoverflow.

changes in Java.inc

```
define ("JAVA_HOSTS", "localhost:8086");
```

...

```
if(!defined("JAVA_HOSTS")) {
    if(!java_defineHostFromInitialQuery(java_get_base())) {
        if ($java_ini=get_cfg_var("java.hosts")) define("JAVA_HOSTS",$java_ini);
        else define("JAVA_HOSTS","127.0.0.1:8086");
    }
}
```

php file content snippet

```
function createBridge() {
    $demo = new java("main.bridge");
    echo 'New Bridge instance created';
    $demo->fn();
    return $demo;
}
```

Here,
running java src folder contains -> "main" folder contains -> "bridge.java" -> fn() function

if mentioned changes are done in java.inc, Fatal error occurs:

> Fatal error: HTTP status 403, Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
>   Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc on line 869

Line 869 refers to 3rd line of below snippet:

```
function dieWithBrokenConnection($msg) {
    unset($this->protocol->client->protocol);
    trigger_error ($msg?$msg:"unknown error: please see back end log for details",E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

And we are using Xampp for local server.
Please let us know if I'm doing something wrong in between or any other useful stuff that can help us out.

Comment: could you also share error message ??

Comment: if mentioned changes are done in java.inc:
_Fatal error: HTTP status 403, Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
in C:\xampp\htdocs\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc on line 869
_
Line 869 refers to 3rd line of below snippet:

`function dieWithBrokenConnection($msg) {

unset($this->protocol->client->protocol);

trigger_error ($msg?$msg:"unknown error: please see back end log for details",E_USER_ERROR);
}`

Comment: can you check if `C:\xampp\htdocs\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc` exists ?? Also, make sure filename has same case.

Comment: yes i have cross-checked the location, file exists and have same case.

Comment: which OS are you using ? could you also check the file permission ?

Comment: OS is windows 8.1 and all required file permissions are granted i.e. read, write, modify, execute ... and without modifying the Java.inc file, below snippet works correctly.
`<?php require_once("java/Java.inc");

$abc = new Java("java.lang.String", "hello!!");
echo $abc;

?>
`

Comment: Ok fine. So, how are you trying to access your java class ? I mean .. have you created jar of it ?

Comment: no. I'm running this java project in eclipse as apache tomcat server at port numbers: tomcat admin port:8006, HTTP/1.1: 8086, AJP/1.3: 8010

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting. Where is this class written `main.bridge` ? It's in your webapp ? or standalone app ?

Comment: yes, class is within webapp project folder i.e. "webAppProject" -> "src"-> "main" package -> bridge.java

Comment: if you read this post, I think you are doing it wrong 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204116/how-to-call-custom-java-methods-from-php

Comment: We followed the link provided by you and we got stuck as, http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/ or http://localhost:8086/JavaBridge/ is not working.(we started the tomcat from eclipse itself) . Do we have to import our webAppProject inside "tomcat\webapps" folder explictly? or location of project does not matter?

Comment: Lets chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139693/trouble-getting-link-to-user-defined-java-class-from-php-using-php-javabridge

Comment: I can guide you over chat

Comment: i don't have enough reputations to chat on stackoverflow... any other alternative?

Comment: Let me see, if I can do anything

Comment: Could you check now ?

Comment: no still not able to chat over that link.

Comment: thing is , it is very difficult to talk/understand over comment.

Comment: It seems like you have two web server . You need to deploy webAppProject explicitly. Then, try accessing it localhost:port/webAppProject

Comment: i understand that, can this be possible over any other resources like gmail or anything? 
we are using xampp and path of the project is not accessible i.e. localhost:port/webAppProject is not running

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. I hope.. you would have copied my email id.

Comment: Just in case, I've set up some doc for tomcat installation http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/install_server/#quick-install. They are based on a javabridge fork https://github.com/belgattitude/php-java-bridge, you'll find some tips that I hope could help