# How to run JAR file using php script?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge, java-bridge-method

I tried JAVA bridge to get output from my jar file  followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10253798/1870048, I am using XAMP Server and from that Apache and Tomcat server is been used

```
  require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");     
  $cartObj = Java("Cart"); //Javav("Cart");
  $cartObj->Cart("098765");
  $cartObj->setLang("EN");
  echo  $cartObj->getLang();
```

but gives error :
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Javav() 
What should I exactly I look into?

Also I tried below way also to call the jar file by placing the jar file in my zampp htdoc folder: (D:\xampp\htdocs\jar)

```
//  Using shell_exec
exec('java -jar AutoDiscounts.jar '.$jsonRequest.' 2>&1', $result);
print_r($result);

//  Using shell_exec
$arg1 = $jsonRequest;//"My_INPUT_PARAMETER";
$output = '';
$output =shell_exec("java -jar AutoDiscounts.jar $arg1");
echo "Done calling shell exec:";
echo $output;
```

But both  above cases does not give any output .Basically my jar will do some cart processing and return output and it works in the JDevloper

[image]

Comment: Is `Java.inc` in the PHP language? Does it define a class for `Javav`?

Comment: @GetSet yes there was no such function  but now I checked there is Java function so changed the function name now  but gives another error

Comment: Javabridge is a network based protocol, you can't just include the jar... you need a server (with jar's you need), There's a standalone version, but I suggest to have a look to https://belgattitude.github.io/soluble-japha/ first. It's a reworked version of the javabridge...